# Does simple "Simple Past" express "Scheduled or Timetabled Future Event in the past" just as "Simple present" does in the present?

Tags: tenses, simple-past

[Englishpage.com](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html) says:

> USE 3 Scheduled Events in the Near Future
>
> Speakers occasionally use Simple Present to talk about scheduled
>   events in the near future. This is most commonly done when talking
>   about public transportation, but it can be used with other scheduled
>   events as well.
>
> Examples:
>
> *The train leaves tonight at 6 PM.*
>
> *The bus does not arrive at 11 AM tomorrow*

[Vivquarry.com](http://www.vivquarry.com/wkshts/narrative.html) says

[image: Timeline]

> Depending on the situation, the following tenses are used in the
>   future in the past:   The past simple (a timetabled event)     .....

So, we have to say: "*Today is Monday. That day was Tuesday last week. And according its timetable, the train left at 6PM the next morning (ie on Wednesday Morning last week)*"

And I would say it is wrong to say "*.....the train would leave at 6PM the next morning...*"

Because this is a Future scheduled event in the past.

But I am not sure my guessing is right or not.

Does simple "**Simple Past**" express "**Scheduled or Timetabled Future Event in the past**" just as "**Simple present**" does in the present?

Comment: You might want to make that 6am the next morning, or just 6:00.

Comment: Uh… Tom, could you please rephrase all of that at least two different ways? What you posted makes no sense. 

For instance, *The bus does not arrive at 11 AM tomorrow* is pure nonsense.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, it is from well-known English site

Comment: Thanks, Tom and when it's from a well-known English site, could you post a link, please?

It might not be impossible to justify *The bus does not arrive at 11 AM tomorrow* as being grammatical and that doesn't mean it's semantically useful. It's certainly unidiomatic.

Idiomatically, that would be something like *There is no 11 AM bus tomorrow* or *The 11 AM bus doesn't run tomorrow*.

Don't hold your breath waiting to hear a native use *The bus doesn't arrive at 11 AM tomorrow*, nor try to compare that to *The train leaves tonight at 6 PM*. The naegation makes too much difference.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, didn't you see the link in the question? https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html

Comment: Ah, thanks, Tom. I'm sorry and no, I didn't see that. I'm doubly sorry but what you posted is not *from well-known English site*… it's a distortion with different grammar, punctuation and meaning.

Sorry and you’re trying to take on far too many things at once and all of them belong to English Language Learners.

Tom, you changed the example out of all recognition. *The bus does not arrive at 11 AM, it arrives at 11 PM* is not what you posted nor is it comparable to what you posted nor, come to that, is it a good example.

More…

Comment: More…

Tom, your link didn't deal with Simple Past, even as compared to Simple Present.

Even if none of that were true, other than *It was due tomorrow* Simple Past could not express anything Future, let alone any Scheduled or Timetabled Future Event in the past.